# Using UISegmentedControl with UISearchController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How do i use `SegmentedControl` with `UISearchController`? I need the `SegmentedControl` to be under the `SearchBar` when `SearchBar` is inactive and hide the segmented control when `SearchBar` is activated.

I put SearchController.searchBar to the tableview header, so the `SegmentedControl` which i defined in storyboard is overlapped by `SearchBar`. When i tried to add `SegmentedControl` programmatically in viewDidLoad by calling tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(customSecmentedControl), it overlapped the cells in tableView.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to wire up your own segmented control to handle this, as that functionality is already provided by `UISearchController`.

Use the search bar's `scopeButtonTitles` property to set the titles for your scope bar:

```
searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Small", "Medium", "Large"]
```

You can determine the selected scope by accessing the search bar's `selectedScopeButtonIndex` property.

The search bar sends its delegate notifications when the scope changes:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int)
```

More details about the scope bar are provided in the [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html) and [UISearchBarDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html) documentation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried to use scopeBar as described here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial.
But, as far as i know, scopeBar appears only when the 'SearchBar' is active. I need segmented control to be presented when search is inactive and hide it when user is searching something in tableView.

Comment: You will have to hide and show it on your own, but the methods in [`UISearchControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchControllerDelegate_Ref/) should be useful in accomplishing that.

Comment: @FilippIgnatov Another approach would be to place a segmented control in the navigation bar `titleView`.  Since the searchBar overlays the navigation bar, it would hide your control when searching.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true

    }
```