# Place UISegmentedControl below title in NavigationBar with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to mimic the behavior seen in iBooks where there is a UISegmentedControl attached to the bottom of the navigation bar.

I understand that this behavior is achievable by attaching a Toolbar and SegmentedControl to the bottom of the UINavigationItem and removing the hairline so they look connected, but I am unsure of how to achieve the search behavior seen in the app. The search bar behaves as if it is a UISearchController set to the navigationItem.searchController in the way that it shows/hides, but it is attached to the bottom of the toolbar/SegmentedControl instead of the NavigationItem.

[image: NavigationBar/SegmentedControl with search hidden]

[image: NavigationBar/SegmentedControl with search partially showing after pulling tableview down]

[image: Search bar fully showing]

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to have a *permanent* SegmentedControl bar below the NavigationItem but above a UISearchBar that shows and hides as if it's a SearchController attached to the NavigationItem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using UISegmentedControl with UISearchController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290396/using-uisegmentedcontrol-with-uisearchcontroller)

Comment: I've read through that one, but I'm trying to achieve a behavior where the SegmentedController is permanent (unlike the scope bar) and _above_ the hide-able search bar